# replaceobjectatindex in NSMutableArray of Dictionaries

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutablearray which is a multi-dimensional array

```
tblarry = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<temp0.count; i++)
{
     NSMutableDictionary *tempDicts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
     [tempDicts setObject:[temp0 objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"UserId"];
     [tempDicts setObject:[temp1 objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"Name"];

     [tblarry addObject:tempDicts];
 }

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
[tblarry sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

In the above code, `temp0` is the `NSmutablearray` with some userids, and the `temp1` is the `NSmutablearray` with names.

I have added the both arrays to the `NSMutablearray`(`tblarry`) and sorted by names.

Now I want to change the value of first object in the sub-array with names with the below code

```
[[[tblarry replaceObjectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Name"] withObject:@"first name"];
```

But it shows the error

`No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'replaceObjectAtIndex:'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using a multi-dimensional array - you have an array of dictionaries. Retrieve the dictionary and then set a new value for the `Name` key.

```
NSMutableDictionary *userDictionary = [tblarry objectAtIndex:0]; //First user
[userDictionary setObject:@"first name" forKey:@"Name"];
```

Comment: `No visible @interface for 'NSMutableDictionary' declares the selector 'setObject:forkey:'` error occurs, what to do?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. It's forKey see edit. `setObject: forKey:` is the same method you use in _your_ code!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Your implementation is incorrect.
The correct way is,

```
  [tblarry replaceObjectAtIndex:[[tblarry objectAtIndex :0] objectForKey:@"Name"] withObject:@"first name"];
```

Now i tell you why it is incorrect,

```
[[[tblarry replaceObjectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Name"] withObject:@"first name"];
```

when you fire `[[tblarry replaceObjectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Name"]` that means you trying to access dictionary inside tblarry but you trying to replaceObjectAtIndex. Your syntax gone wrong here. Simply you conflict.

If you want save dictionary inside array,

```
NSDictionary *values = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:num], @"UserId",
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag], @"name",
                        nil];
   [tblarry addObject:values];
While retrieve time ,
  NSInteger  firstValue = [[[tblarry objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"UserId"] intValue];
  NSInteger  tagValue =  [[[tblarry objectAtIndex:0]  objectForKey:@"name"] intValue];
```